# How do I forbid easy_install from zipping eggs?

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

What must I put into `distutils.cfg` to prevent easy_install from ever installing a zipped egg? The compression is a nice thought, but I like to be able to grep through and debug that code.

I pulled in some dependencies with `python setup.py develop .` A closer look reveals that also accepts the --always-unzip flag. It would just be nice to set that as default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the option is zip-ok, so put the following in your distutils.cfg:

```
[easy_install]

# i don't like having zipped files.
zip_ok = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is a setting in distutils.cfg for this, as easy_install is not a part of distutils. But run easy_install like this:

```
easy_install --always-unzip
```

and it should solve the problem.

Comment: easy_install looks for an [easy_install] section in lib/python2.6/distutils/distutils.cfg. It can accept find_links= for example.

Comment: well, alwasy-unzip = true is worth a try, then.

Answer (score 0):

One solution?

```
easy_install pip
rm easy_install
ln -s easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue using buildout, and the solved it by adding:

```
[buildout]
unzip = true
```

in the `buildout.cfg` file