# editing code of a python module

Tags: python, matlab

Running pymatlab on my machine results in

```
Exception AttributeError: "'MatlabSession' object has no attribute 'engine'" in > ignored
```

after the command `session = pymatlab.session_factory()` is run.

How to fix this problem has been discussed already here:

[Running MATLAB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292585/running-matlab-from-python)

It looks like one line of code in the `sessionfactory.py` script in the pymatlab module has to be changed in a minor way. The problem I have is that the pymatlab module which is installed on my machine is in .egg form and it doesn't look like it is possible to change the code directly with a text editor. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use `easy_install`, check
[How do I forbid easy_install from zipping eggs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218058/how-do-i-forbid-easy-install-from-zipping-eggs)

If you prefer `pip` (and you probably [should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)), check 
[pip: “Editable” Installs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs), i.e.

```
pip install -e pymatlab
```